# Check if an XSLT expects parameters?

Tags: c#, xslt

Is there anyway to check with C# code , to see if an XSLT expects parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT is XML, so you can load the file into a `XDocument` and query it to see if there are any parameter elements defined on the top element.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Oded.
I had thought about this approach, I was just wondering if C# had any built in support for this type of check.

Comment: @Jordan - The XML libraries are generic, they don't have specific XSLT support outside of transformations, definitely nothing on the query side.

Comment: @Oded: Strictly speaking this answer is *wrong* as any global parameter must not be defined inside of a template. Global parameters are children of the top element -- the `xsl:stylesheet` or `xsl:transform` element. See my answer, which is correct. Hope you'll correct the wrong statement.

Answer (score 0):

**Evaluate this XPath expression against the XML document that contains the XSLT file**:

```
/*/xsl:param
```

If the result contains at least one node, then the xslt stylesheet contains at least one global `xsl:param` -- and the main purpose of a global `xsl:param` is to be set externally by the invoker of the transformation.

where you have to add the XSLT namespace and associate it with the `"xsl:"` prefix using an `XmlNamespaceManager` object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and code sample Dimitre.
I had already implemented this expression after Oled's suggestion , hence why I accepted his answer.

Comment: @Jordan: Please, read my comment to @_Oded's answer in which I explain why this answer is wrong.